# CTE issue,error on execution.Unable to create a summary report

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I want to create a summary report.I am totally new to CTE.

Error details:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Code:

```
WITH T1(PlannedFY, Media_Activity_Type.[Type], ReportingQuarter, Summary, ID) AS  
(
    SELECT 
       COUNT(MediaActivities.MediaActivityId) AS [PlannedFY],
       Media_Activity_Type.[Type] AS [ID], 
       MediaActivities.ReportingQuarter, 
       MediaActivities.Summary,
       MediaActivities.TypeId
    FROM 
       Media_Activity_Type 
    INNER JOIN
       MediaActivities ON Media_Activity_Type.TypeId = MediaActivities.TypeId
    GROUP BY 
       MediaActivities.MediaActivityId, Media_Activity_Type.[Type],  
       MediaActivities.ReportingQuarter, MediaActivities.Achivied, 
       MediaActivities.Summary, MediaActivities.TypeId
),
T2(Achieved, ID) AS
(              
   SELECT     
      COUNT(MediaActivities.Achivied) AS [Achieved], 
      Media_Activity_Type.TypeId AS [ID]
   FROM         
      MediaActivities 
   INNER JOIN
      Media_Activity_Type ON MediaActivities.TypeId = Media_Activity_Type.TypeId
   GROUP BY 
      Media_Activity_Type.TypeId, MediaActivities.Achivied
   HAVING 
      MediaActivities.Achivied = 1
)    
SELECT 
   T1.*, T2.Achieved 
FROM 
   T1     
INNER JOIN 
   T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Answer (score 5):

The "parameters" for the `with` part define column aliases, they do not reference "real" columns. So you should change:

```
WITH T1(PlannedFY,Media_Activity_Type.[Type],ReportingQuarter,Summary,ID)
```

to

```
WITH T1(PlannedFY,[Type],ReportingQuarter,Summary,ID)
```

which says "create a CTE with the columns `PlannedFY`, `[Type]`, `ReportingQuarter`, `Summary` and `ID`

Answer (score 0):

You also are doing a count(MediaActivities.MediaActivityId) and have that in your group by, so you will probably always get a count of 1.
You could simplify the query:

```
WITH T1 AS  
(
    SELECT 
       COUNT(MediaActivities.MediaActivityId) AS [PlannedFY],
       Media_Activity_Type.[Type] AS [ID], 
       MediaActivities.ReportingQuarter, 
       MediaActivities.Summary,
       MediaActivities.TypeId
    FROM 
       Media_Activity_Type 
    INNER JOIN
       MediaActivities ON Media_Activity_Type.TypeId = MediaActivities.TypeId
    GROUP BY 
     --  MediaActivities.MediaActivityId,
       Media_Activity_Type.[Type],  
       MediaActivities.ReportingQuarter,
       MediaActivities.Achivied, 
       MediaActivities.Summary,
       MediaActivities.TypeId
),
T2 AS
(              
   SELECT     
      COUNT(MediaActivities.Achivied) AS [Achieved], 
      Media_Activity_Type.TypeId AS [ID]
   FROM         
      MediaActivities 
   INNER JOIN
      Media_Activity_Type ON MediaActivities.TypeId = Media_Activity_Type.TypeId
   GROUP BY 
      Media_Activity_Type.TypeId, MediaActivities.Achivied
   HAVING 
      MediaActivities.Achivied = 1
)    
SELECT 
   T1.*, T2.Achieved 
FROM 
   T1     
INNER JOIN 
   T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```